# Align attribute still available in HTML5?

Tags: css, html, alignment

Is it still possible to add the align attribute to a HTML element to align the element itself? So that it's not set via CSS but in the element tag itself, something like this:

```html
<div align="center"></div>
```

Will this still center it, or will the attribute just be ignored?

Comment: that attribute is deprecated use css values like `text-align`

Comment: `<div class="main" style="text-align:center;">` Now question is... you have a class already, why not declare that in the class in css?

Comment: @david and gio: OP clearly asked to align the div itself, not the div's inline contents.

Comment: Use { margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: The `align` attribute is deprecated in HTML 4, and **removed** in HTML 5. Don't use it: use CSS instead.

Comment: @BalusC: not so clear, as you can tell from the other comment as well.  so he would need to do `style="margin:auto;"`

Comment: @gio: OP wants to achieve the same effect as `align="center"`. This is clearly not `text-align:center`. The `margin:auto;` is still wrong. Are you also new to CSS or so?

Comment: margin auto will work, if the width is defined, but we have no idea with the given code

Comment: Why don't you validate it and find out?

Comment: @BalusC: It should work, considering you have some proper code behind it... Cant really tell from what was provided... Oh and I dont really work with deprecated/removed properties, so I'm usually unfamiliar with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mike W pointed out in the comments:

> The align attribute is deprecated in HTML 4, and removed in HTML 5.
>   Don't use it: use CSS instead.

That being said, here are some ways to center it anyway, even though you say you have more elements with that class.

Give this specific element inline style:

```
<div class="main" style="margin: auto;">
```

Be more specific in your CSS. The element is probably a child of an element that does not have any other `.main` babies, so you can specify this element by using the parent element in CSS:

```
.parent-class > .main {margin: auto;} /* If the parent has a class */
#parent-id > .main {margin: auto;} /* If the parent has an ID. This one is prefered, to avoid misunderstandings */
```

If the above is not the case, and there are multiple instances of `.main` within a single parent, you can use the `nth-child` selector (or `first-child` or `last-child`). For instance, if the element you want to center is the third child within the parent element, use this code.

```
.main:nth-child(3) {margin: auto;}
```

Answer (score 2):

why dont you use 
`<div class="main" style="margin:0 auto;">`